# excel file is not saving to the macro specified filepath

Tags: excel, vba, filepath

I have a simple macro that I want to use daily, it works fine other that it does not save where I would like it to.

Rather than saving in the desired shared network folder, it is saving in 'Documents' folder.  Please help.

```
Dim FilePath As String
Dim NewName As String

FilePath = "G:\Pricing\Gas Pricing Models\Wholesale\Basis Strips": NewName = "NYMEX" & Format(Date, "MM-DD-YYYY") & ".xlsm"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewName, FileFormat _
:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-30
End Sub
```

Comment: While the answer from Arich is the best approach, note that you can also set the default directory using `ChDir`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Filename` argument of the `SaveAs` method should also include the filepath of the file. If you don't include the filepath in that argument, the file is saved to the current folder. [See this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) for more information.

Your code should look like this, then:

**Untested**

```
FilePath = "G:\Pricing\Gas Pricing Models\Wholesale\Basis Strips\"  
NewName = "NYMEX" & Format(Date, "MM-DD-YYYY") & ".xlsm"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath & NewName, FileFormat _
    :=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
```

Note the added backslash at the end of the `FilePath` string.